# Why is my recent netbeans 7.3 installation having these dependency problems during attempted plugin update?

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-7, netbeans-plugins

Some plugins require plugin Editor Library to be installed.
The plugin Editor Library is requested in version >= 2.1 (release version 2) but only 3.33.3.21.40 (of release version different from 2) was found.  The following plugin is affected:       Spellchecker Java Language Bindings

Some plugins require plugin Java Profiler (Attach Support) to be installed.
The plugin Java Profiler (Attach Support) is requested in version >= 1.0 (release version 1) but only 2.8.1 (of release version different from 1) was found.  The following plugin is affected:       Java Profiler (Attach - SJSAS/GlassFish Support)

Some plugins require plugin Java Profiler Core to be installed.
The plugin Java Profiler Core is requested in version >= 1.6 (release version 1) but only 2.9.1 (of release version different from 1) was found.  The following plugin is affected:       Java Profiler (Attach - SJSAS/GlassFish Support)  Some plugins not installed to avoid potential installation problems

Comment: Curious to know the solution as well, instead of just re-installing everything.

Answer (score 0):

Third paragraph also appeared in Netbeans 8.1. Cannot go further, can't delete it, cannot skip it :(

```
Some plugins require plugin Java Profiler (Attach Support) to be installed.
=> 1.0 (release version 1) but only 2.15.1 (of release version different 
from 1) was found.
The following plugins are affected:
Java Profiler (Glassfish support)
Java Profiler (JBoss support)
Java Profiler (Tomcat support)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. What worked for me is making sure the updates.xml file matches the Java ME SDK version (I had downloaded the 8.0 plugins/updater when my SDK version was 8.3).

Click here to go to the [Java ME SDK Download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/javame/javame-sdk/downloads/index.html) page. Download the "oracle-jmesdk-8-3-rr-nb-plugins.zip" (for version 8.3) and unzip it into a directory.

Link the updates.xml file by going to Tools > Plugins, clicking on "Settings", and either editing the Java ME updater, or adding it, with the "Add" button. I called mine "Java ME SDK Plug-ins Update Center".

After adding this updater, go to "Available Plugins", click "Check for Newest" and re-select the packages you want.

Hope this helps!